# How to manage textarea right side overflow in css?

Tags: html, css, css-float, textarea, overflow

I have to create two `<textarea>`s in two different `<div>`s and  both are have to come in single line. And both `<textarea>`s have to occupy 100% width (50% by each) in all types of screen.

However, when I am trying the second `<textarea>`, the right side is overflowing and even I am not able to manage right margin (in CSS) for `<textarea>`. How can I avoid right overflow for `<textarea>`?

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 5px solid black;
  min-height: 500px;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px none #cccccc;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='left'>
  <textarea>left </textarea>
</div> 
<div class='right'>
  <textarea>right</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code? Stack snippet or http://jsfiddle.net is preferable.

Comment: please edit your question and add the code in it instead of the un readable comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove margin from your textarea because margin calculated form the outer width of the element, and give display: table; to container.

Comment: How can I archive 100% height ?

Comment: html,body.container{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

Answer (score 1):

Note the change in margin to `textarea`. That should do it!

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 5px solid black;
  min-height: 500px;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px none #cccccc;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='left'>
  <textarea>left</textarea>
</div>
<div class='right'>
  <textarea>right</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove `margin` from your `textarea` because `margin` calculated form the outer width of the element , you can use `padding` to `.conatiner` instead.

and add a `box-sizing` attribute to remove the border width from the calculate width

```css
html,body,.container{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.container{ 
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding:10px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} 
textarea { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px none #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} 
.left{ 
  display: table-cell;
  width:50%;
  height: 100%;
} 
.right{ 
  display: table-cell; 
  width:50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<div class="container">
<div class='left'>
  <textarea>left </textarea>
</div> 
<div class='right'>
  <textarea>right</textarea>
</div>
  </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Its working well ,  now how can I give 100% height to both textarea?

Comment: @mahi check my answer now and note the change in left and right divs

Comment: Its working well now tell me how can I archive 100% height ?

Comment: Its now 100% height .. check the new edits in the answer

Comment: I want 100% height in all screen .  Ur code using  **min-height: 500px;**  in container , plz remove   **min-height: 500px;** and make it by % basis

Comment: `min-height:500px` is your code not mine :) , anyway I fixed it and it's now 100% height of whole page height

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin. Because you are assigning 50% to each left and right textarea. so your total width will be 100%+10px; so it will overflow on x-axis

```
textarea {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 3px none #cccccc;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: if you want to give margin. then give it in percentage say 2% and have width of 49% in both textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframes for that. If you use iframes you can fit the overflow to hidden both left and right side